# Jsonwebtoken check jwt and return TokenClaims or Error

Tags: generics, rust, jwt

I am trying to build a function to check if a provided token is valid or not, using jsonwebtoken crate.
But, I am struggling to make it working, because I don't know what import I should use for Error.

```
pub fn check_jwt(token: String) -> Result<TokenClaims, Error> {
let secretKey = "supersecret"; //std::env::var("RSA_KEY");

let claims = decode::<TokenClaims>(
    &token,
    &DecodingKey::from_secret(secretKey.as_ref()),
    &Validation::default(),
)
.map_err(|_| {
    let json_error = ErrorResponse {
        status: "fail",
        message: "Invalid token".to_string(),
    };
    (StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED, Json(json_error))
})?.claims;
println!("claims: {:?}", claims);
Ok(claims)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this line:

> (StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED, Json(json_error))

Your return type should be `Result<TokenClaim, (StatusCode, Json)`.

Note that the `Json` part of this may be different though depending on the return type of `Json(...)`. This can be found in the documentation for the function.